# Empty outputs with python GDAL

Tags: gdal, ogr

Hello im new to Gdal and im struggling a with my codes. Everything seems to go well in my code mut the output bands at the end is empty. The no data value is set to 256 when i specify 255, so I don't really know whats wrong. Thanks any help will be appreciated!!!

Here is my code

```
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import gdalconst
from osgeo import osr
from osgeo import ogr
import numpy

#graticule
src_ds = gdal.Open("E:\\NFI_photo_plot\\photoplotdownloadAllCanada\\provincial_merge\\Aggregate\\graticule1.tif")
band = src_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
band.SetNoDataValue(0)
graticule = band.ReadAsArray()
print('graticule done')
band="none"

#Biomass
dataset1 = gdal.Open("E:\\NFI_photo_plot\\photoplotdownloadAllCanada\provincial_merge\\Aggregate\\Biomass_NFI.tif")
band1 = dataset1.GetRasterBand(1)
band1.SetNoDataValue(-1)
Biomass = band1.ReadAsArray()
maskbiomass = numpy.greater(Biomass, -1).astype(int)
print("biomass done")
Biomass="none"
band1="none"
dataset1="none"

#Baseline
dataset2 = gdal.Open("E:\\NFI_photo_plot\\Baseline\\TOTBM_250.tif")
band2 = dataset2.GetRasterBand(1)
band2.SetNoDataValue(0)
baseline = band2.ReadAsArray()
maskbaseline = numpy.greater(baseline, 0).astype(int)
print('baseline done')
baseline="none"
band2="none"
dataset2="none"

#sommation
biosource=(graticule+maskbiomass+maskbaseline)
biosource1=numpy.uint8(biosource)
biosource="none"

#Écriture
dst_file="E:\\NFI_photo_plot\\photoplotdownloadAllCanada\\provincial_merge\\Aggregate\\Biosource.tif"
dst_driver = gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
dst_ds = dst_driver.Create(dst_file, src_ds.RasterXSize,
src_ds.RasterYSize, 1, gdal.GDT_Byte)

#projection
dst_ds.SetProjection( src_ds.GetProjection() )
dst_ds.SetGeoTransform( src_ds.GetGeoTransform() )
outband=dst_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
outband.WriteArray(biosource1,0,0)
outband.SetNoDataValue(255)
biosource="none"
graticule="none"
```

Answer (score 1):

A few pointers:

- Where you have `="none"`, these need to be `= None` to close/cleanup the objects, otherwise you are setting the objects to an array of characters: `n` `o` `n` `e`, which is not what you intend to do.
- Why do you have `band1.SetNoDataValue(-1)`, while other NoData values are 0? Is this data source signed or unsigned? If unsigned, then -1 doesn't exist.
- When you open rasters with [`gdal.Open`](https://gdal.org/api/index.html#raster-api#6836f0f810396c5e45622c8ef94624d4) without the access option, it defaults to `gdal.GA_ReadOnly`, which means your subsequent `SetNoDataValue` calls do nothing. If you want to modify the dataset, you need to use `gdal.GA_Update` as your second parameter to `gdal.Open`.
- Another strategy to create a new raster is to use `driver.CreateCopy`; see the [tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/raster_api_tut.html) for details.